# X11 forwarding from a docker container in remote server

Tags: ssh, x11, docker

I want to ssh into my linux mint 18 server (running X11) and log into a docker container and have iPython matplotlib plots forwarded to the local client (also mint). All in the local network.

The closest question I found was: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25281992/alternatives-to-ssh-x11-forwarding-for-docker-containers

Following this, I could get a plot GUI out from the docker to the local machine's display (e.i., the mint server) by `-e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` option passed to the `docker run` command. I can also ssh with `-X` option to the server to get `xeyes` window to the client.

But if I ssh into the server with `-X` option and login to the container ran with `-DISPLAY=localhost or client IP`, I still cannot get a plot to the client machine.

I know I could use VNC to go around it. But, how can I do this with X11 forwarding properly?

Comment: `DISPLAY=$DISPLAY` should work in the SSH case too (`ssh -X` sets the variable to the appropriate value, it’s not just an IP address). Have you tried that?

Answer (score 16):

You need to resolve these things for it to work:

1. That the X application can find the X server

   - For SSH there needs to be a tunnel ("ssh -X" and "X11Forwarding yes" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config)
   - The address must be in $DISPLAY (using -e). You must replace "localhost" with the actual IP address of the Docker host seen from the Docker container.
2. That the X application is authorised to talk to the X server

   - Propagate the xauth magic cookie into the Docker container
   - Open up any firewall ports from the Docker host to the Docker container for the X11 port
   - Make sure the SSH server is configured to accept X11 TCP connections on a remote IP.

See my question (and answer) here on StackOverflow for details of how it can be done: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48235040/run-x11-application-in-a-docker-container-reliably-on-a-server-connected-via-ssh

Answer (score 8):

To run a GUI app in a remote docker container, you do not need X11 forwarding from the server. 
You can make the X11 server listen on TCP:6000, and run the remote docker container with `-e DISPLAY=$IP:0` , which the $IP is the ip address of computer that run X11 server.

I have got it work on an macbook with XQuarz to display a remote docker container on remote ubuntu:

- On macbook
  use socat to make the X11 server listen on TCP, follow [Running GUI’s with Docker on Mac OS X](https://cntnr.io/running-guis-with-docker-on-mac-os-x-a14df6a76efc).
- On remote ubuntu

```
docker run -it --rm -e DISPLAY=$macbook_ip:0 fr3nd/xeyes
```

Then the xeyes show on the macbook

Answer (score 2):

The Python module **dockerx** is intended to solve this problem.

You can install it running:

```
python3 -m pip install dockerx --user
```

To run a container with X11 support:

```bsh
$ python3 -m dockerx.run --image ubuntu --command 'sleep infinity'

To get a container terminal run:  docker exec -it b05bd722477e /bin/bash
To kill the container run:        docker kill b05bd722477e
To remove the container run:      docker rm b05bd722477e

$ docker exec -it b05bd722477e /bin/bash
root@b05bd722477e:/# apt update && apt install -y x11-apps
root@b05bd722477e:/# xclock
```

After this, you should see `xclock` displayed in your screen.

If you want CUDA support (requires the Docker NVIDIA Runtime to be installed in your system), launch the container using:

```bsh
$ python3 -m dockerx.run --image nvidia/cuda:11.0-base --nvidia 1 --command 'sleep infinity'
```

**dockerx** requires that the SSH server running in the remote computer has the option `X11UseLocalhost no` set in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

For more details, check [the GitHub of the dockerx Python module](https://github.com/luiscarlosgph/dockerx).

Answer (score 1):

**Container:**

```
cp /etc/ssh/sshd_config /etc/ssh/sshd_config_bak

sed -i "s/^.*X11Forwarding.*$/X11Forwarding yes/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config 

sed -i "s/^.*X11UseLocalhost.*$/X11UseLocalhost no/" /etc/ssh/sshd_config 

grep "^X11UseLocalhost" /etc/ssh/sshd_config || echo "X11UseLocalhost no" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

**Client:**

```
ssh -X user@ip
```

**Reference:**

[udkyo/Dockerfile](https://gist.github.com/udkyo/c20935c7577c71d634f0090ef6fa8393)

Comment: You mean that you ssh directly into the container?

Comment: X11UseLocalhost no ... definitely useful, turned out to be the missing link once I'd got the rest of the DISPLAY and .Xauthority stuff set up.